# Problem with react forwardref warning in console

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi i have following code. I want to style on my own material ui button using styled-components library:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'

import { Button as MuiButton } from '@material-ui/core';

interface SimpleProps<T extends string> {
  random?: T;
}

interface Props {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    isCircled?: boolean;
}

function StyledButton<T extends string>(
  props: Props & SimpleProps<T> & { ref?: React.Ref<HTMLButtonElement> }
) {
  type CombinedProps = Props & SimpleProps<T>;
  const Forwarded = styled(React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, CombinedProps>(
    ({ children, isCircled, ...rest }, ref) => (
      <MuiButton ref={ref} {...rest}>
                {children}
            </MuiButton>
    )
    ))`
        background-color: green!important;
        border-radius: ${(props) => props.isCircled ? '25px' : '10px'}!important;
    `;
    return <Forwarded {...props} />
}

const Button: React.FC = (props: any) => {
    const { children } = props;
    const ref = React.useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);

    return (
        <StyledButton ref={ref}>
            {children}
        </StyledButton>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

and in console i can see an warning:

```
Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

How to remove this warning? What am i doing wrong in this implementation? I can't find any solution...

Comment: Do you understand my response ?

Answer (score 0):

> In fact, the rule of React : refs will not get passed through. That’s
>   because **ref** is not a prop. Like **key** **in map()**, it’s handled
>   differently by React.

Beacause of that, you should use the technique **Forwarding Refs** (https://en.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) for passing ref into the child component. Example of React official documentation :

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

In your code snippet, you should do as below :

```
const StyledButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref }
) {
  type CombinedProps = Props & SimpleProps<T>;
  const Forwarded = styled(React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, CombinedProps>(
    ({ children, isCircled, ...rest }, ref) => (
      <MuiButton ref={ref} {...rest}>
                {children}
            </MuiButton>
    )
    ))`
        background-color: green!important;
        border-radius: ${(props) => props.isCircled ? '25px' : '10px'}!important;
    `;
    return <Forwarded {...props} />
});
```

Comment: Putting the ref prop on `FancyButton` triggers similar console warnings: `Warning: [object Object]: 'ref' is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in 'undefined' being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.`